# iOS App works fine when deployed from xcode, but more crash prone on MKMapView when installed from iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I have a tab based app that uses four tabs. The home tab is an MKMapView. When I load the app onto my iPhone and run from "Xcode" or "Instruments" there are no problems with crashing. However when I load the app onto my iPhone from iTunes or testflight.com it crashes whenever the MKMapView pans or zooms. Everything else in the app seems to work fine.

Comment: Where is the crash report? Have you run Analyzer? Using ARC? Blocks? There is really not much to go on.

Comment: I'm using ARC. I don't know where to get the crash report when I run the app from iTunes. If by "Analyzer" you mean the tool in X-Code, I've run that. What kind of information would you need from Analyzer? Is there any other information that would be useful?

Comment: There should be no error or warnings from Analyzer. does it crash when you run the app from iTunes? By iTunes do you mean the AppStore? Minimal crash reports are available from iTunes Connect.

Comment: I do get a few notices in Analyzer. Mostly relating to mallocing, and nothing related to the mapview. By running it from iTunes I mean that I load my app onto my iPhone directly using iTunes. I open iTunes. Click on File >> Add to Library, and then install my .ipa file directly onto my iPhone.

Comment: First thing: Fix all analyzer issues and all warnings.

Comment: I've eliminated quite a few issues and warnings. There are a few warnings because X-code claims to not be able to find certain method definitions even though I've verified that they're there. And the analyzer has tagged a couple variables as "garbage" even though in the course of running the app the values are used. It still crashes when I try to pan or zoom, and only when I run the app independently of X-code.

Comment: In Analyzer if you click on the blue icons in the code, not the left margin, the path through the code that produced the message will be shown graphically. In any case, make all changes needed to eliminate all warnings, there is a reason for each. Work on understanding what the tools are trying to tell you. Sure just fixing all warnings may not resolve the crashes but the still need to be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the iOS version of simulator and device both? this might be happening due to some method or something else which might be not exist in the running version of iOS and your code might be calling that particular method.

You should debug your code while running on device and track the specific action as your were saying crashed happens when only the pan or zooming of mapview performed.

Comment: Thanks Kamarshad. Actually I have not ran it on the simulator recently. I've been debugging it on the device using X-Code and not experiencing any problems. It's only when I install the ipa file on my iPhone using iTunes that panning and zooming crashes the app. To answer your question though, my iPhone runs iOS7 and my simulator runs iOS6.1.

Comment: If it helps at I have a UIAlert that suggests more efficient ways of navigating the map to the user. It's supposed to be triggered from low memory warnings. And a couple of times I've seen that alert just before the app crashes.